# Configuration space of three points in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$

Tags: classical-mechanics

If $X,Y,Z$ are the distances between three points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $X,Y,Z$ satisfy the triangle inequality. What will be the configuration space of the three points, given the translation symmetry (fix one point at origin).

Thanks

Comment: Won't the distances between any three points always satisfy the triangle inequality (hence the name)? Or am I misunderstanding the first sentence?

Comment: they could be collinear.

Comment: The formulation of the triangle inequality I have usually seen is with a $\leq$, not a $<$ - perhaps you could specify in your question that you mean the *strict* triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't know how configuration spaces are usually specified, but we have one point at the origin, the second point can be chosen anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\cong\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and then the third point can be chosen anywhere off the line connecting the first two points, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a line, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. So the configuration space would be
$$\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}^2$$
Or are you looking for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^9$?

Comment: @Zev: it's a non-trivial bundle over $S^2\times\mathbb{R}_+$ (with the fibre $S^1\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$), not just a product

Comment: @ Zev - This seems correct, but the idea I have is this. The first point at origin, then the second can be anywhere on a sphere of radius $X$ around origin and the third on the sphere of radius $Y$ around Ist point and also on the sphere of radius $Z$ around 2nd point.I am not sure though if this is correct. I expect it to be 4d.

Comment: @ user8268 - can you say something more about this.may be as answer.thanks.

Comment: @user8268 - Ah, you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the question is not very clear, so I'm not sure whether this is an answer:
If the distances $X,Y,Z$ are *fixed* and satisfy strict triangle inequality then the configuration space is (diffeomorphic to) $SO(3)\cong\mathbb{RP}^3$, as $SO(3)$ acts freely and transitively on this configuration space. If they are not fixed and you simply want to exclude configurations of collinear points then you get $SO(3)\times\{(X,Y,Z)\in\mathbb{R}_+^3;X,Y,Z$ satisfy strict triangle ineqality $\}$ which is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)\times\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: can you say more about how it is diffeomorphic to $SO(3)$.

Comment: @J Verma: take a preferred configuration - e.g. (the 1st point is the origin) the 2nd point is on the positive half of the $x$ axis and the 3rd point is right above this half axis. Any other configuration can be obtained from this preferred one via unique rotation. That's how you identify configurations with rotations.

Comment: @ user8268 - thanks.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion (in detail) of this in a book by David Kendall et al called Shape Theory. They discuss probability distributions on the configuration space and then the idea of a random triangle.

Comment: @ Tim - Can you tell me exact chapter of the book.Thanks.